# Mapping a drive and backing up a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-3.0

We back up our SQL Server databases to NAS, and was curious if it would be possible to back up to a temporary mapped drive, as opposed to the UNC path.  I'm hitting a wall.

Using New-PSDrive:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "Y" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\NAS\Backups" -Scope Global -Persist

Test-Path "Y:\SQLDBA" <# returns True #>

<# Method 1 #>
sqlcmd -E -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [SQLDBA] TO DISK = N'Y:\SQLDBA\SQLDBA.bak' WITH INIT" -b
<# Method 2 #>
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database master -Query "BACKUP DATABASE [SQLDBA] TO DISK = N'Y:\SQLDBA\SQLDBA.bak' WITH INIT" -QueryTimeout 999999999 -verbose -ErrorAction Stop  

Remove-PSDrive "Y"
```

Using net use:

```
net use Y: \\NAS\Backups /persistent:yes

<# Method 1 #>
sqlcmd -E -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [SQLDBA] TO DISK = N'Y:\SQLDBA\SQLDBA.bak' WITH INIT" -b
<# Method 2 #>
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database master -Query "BACKUP DATABASE [SQLDBA] TO DISK = N'Y:\SQLDBA\SQLDBA.bak' WITH INIT" -QueryTimeout 999999999 -verbose -ErrorAction Stop  

net use Y: /delete
```

Either method gets me the same error:

Cannot open backup device 'Y:\SQLDBA\SQLDBA.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

Is this possible?

Comment: Is the file already configured as a backup device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not. Mapped drives exist in a Session. The server process (of sql server) has it's own session, so it does not see your mapped drive.

Answer (score 2):

To back up to a network drive when SQL Server is running in a domain user account, the shared drive must be mapped as a network drive in the session where SQL Server is running. If you start Sqlservr.exe from command line, SQL Server sees any network drives you have mapped in your login session.

Please check the following article for reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179313.aspx#NetworkShare